# Which is a better way to search from multiple tables using PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML form where there is a search field to type for a product name, and below are checkboxes, each for one shop where the product name is to be searched. Users can search from multiple shops by checking the boxes. The form sends a GET request to server, where there is a database with separate tables for separate shops.

```
<form action="price.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="query" name="query" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shop1" id="shop1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shop2" id="shop2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

So in server side I have written a PHP code that will search for the product name from those tables that correspond to the shops checked by the user. **Since I will be adding more and more shops in the future, which of the following PHP codes are better suited?**

**VERSION 1**

```
<?php
function search($pdo, $shop) {
if ( isset($_GET[$shop]) && ($_GET['query'] !== "") ) {
    switch ($shop) {
        case "shop1":
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `shop1` WHERE `name` LIKE :query");
            $stmt->execute(array(":query" => "%". $_GET['query'] . "%"));
            break;
        case "shop2":
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `shop2` WHERE `name` LIKE :query");
            $stmt->execute(array(":query" => "%". $_GET['query'] . "%"));
            break;
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ( count($rows) === 0 ) {
        $_SESSION[$shop] = 'nothing found from '. $shop;
        return array();
    } else {
        return $rows;
    }
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

if ( ! isset($_GET['query']) ) {
    $_SESSION['success'] = "search for an item";
} else {
    $rowsShop1 = search($pdo, "shop1");
    $rowsShop2 = search($pdo, "shop2");
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
?>
```

**VERSION 2**

```
<?php
function search1($pdo, $shop, $sql) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(":query" => "%". $_GET['query'] . "%"));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ( count($rows) === 0 ) {
        $_SESSION[$shop] = 'nothing found from '. $shop;
        return array();
    } else {
        return $rows;
    }
}

if ( ! isset($_GET['query']) ) {
    $_SESSION['success'] = "search for an item";
} else {
    if ( isset($_GET['shop1']) && ($_GET['query'] !== "") ) {
        $rowsShop1 = search1($pdo, "shop1", "SELECT * FROM `shop1` WHERE `name` LIKE :query");
    }
    if ( isset($_GET['shop2']) && ($_GET['query'] !== "") ) {
        $rowsShop2 = search1($pdo, "shop2", "SELECT * FROM `shop2` WHERE `name` LIKE :query");
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
?>
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't know how many shops you might come to have but this looks like a nightmare to maintain. In your place I would just change the structure of your database. Create a table `shop` listing your shops, a table called `product` to stock your products and a n..n relation with a table like `shop_product` where you would have the `shop_id`, the `product_id` and the `quantity`

Comment: If you find yourself searching more than one similar table, you'll quite often want to fix your schema rather than your code. It sounds like each table has a list of products in it, would it be easier to just have a single `products` table, and a shop column to distinguish them?

Comment: If you want to keep your data model with individual tables for each shop, then I’d _start_ by making the checkbox values submit in array format, by using `name="shop[]"` for all of them - then you get an array in `$_GET['shop']`, that you can easily loop over.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, you're right. I should have done that. But now it looks like I need to change my data model, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go further than my comment, here is a fiddle so you can try the database model I described : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPuc6P87MYuKKBYwztvK7X/0

This can allow you to easily manage your shops and products through their own CRUD without having to work in several tables.

Here below the SQL code if the fiddle somehow doesn't work anymore. (assuming MySQL / MariaDB)

```
create table product
(
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    constraint product_pk
        primary key (id)
);

create table shop
(
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    constraint shop_pk
        primary key (id)
);

create table product_shop
(
  id int auto_increment,
  product_id int,
  shop_id int,
  quantity int not null default 0,
  constraint product_shop_pk
      primary key (id)
);

alter table product_shop
    add constraint product_shop_product_fk
        foreign key (product_id) references product (id);
alter table product_shop
    add constraint product_shop_shop_fk
        foreign key (shop_id) references shop (id);
```

Comment: yes, this data model would meet my needs, and reduce the lines of php code. Thanks!